# OOM Exception Hiveserver 2

Tags: java, hive, jvm, hadoop2, mapr

I have configured `HADOOP_HEAPSIZE` as 12288m in hive-env.sh,though still am getting the OOM exception and i had to restart the hiveserver2 often!!?

and when i do the ps grep on hiveserver,

```
mapr      4824     1  0 Apr05 ?        00:00:53 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.131.x86_64/bin/java -Xmx12288m -Dhiveserver2.auth=NONE -Dhadoop.login=simple -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/mapr/conf/mapr.login.conf -Dzookeeper.sasl.clientconfig=Client_simple -Dzookeeper.saslprovider=com.mapr.security.simplesasl.SimpleSaslProvider -Dmapr.library.flatclass -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0 -Dhadoop.id.str=mapr -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx512m -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/mapr/conf/mapr.login.conf -Dzookeeper.sasl.clientconfig=Client_simple -Dzookeeper.saslprovider=com.mapr.security.simplesasl.SimpleSaslProvider org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar /opt/mapr/hive/hive-1.2/lib/hive-service-1.2.0-mapr-1603.jar org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2
mapr     17943     1  0 Apr03 ?        00:03:13 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.131.x86_64/bin/java -Xmx256m -Dhiveserver2.auth=NONE -Dhadoop.login=simple -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/mapr/conf/mapr.login.conf -Dzookeeper.sasl.clientconfig=Client_simple -Dzookeeper.saslprovider=com.mapr.security.simplesasl.SimpleSaslProvider -Dmapr.library.flatclass -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0 -Dhadoop.id.str=mapr -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx512m -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/mapr/conf/mapr.login.conf -Dzookeeper.sasl.clientconfig=Client_simple -Dzookeeper.saslprovider=com.mapr.security.simplesasl.SimpleSaslProvider org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar /opt/mapr/hive/hive-1.2/lib/hive-service-1.2.0-mapr-1603.jar org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore
mapr     27048 25765  0 09:16 pts/1    00:00:00 grep -i hiveserver2
```

It seems that JVM treats the rightmost instance of an argument as the winner,so in my case the right most value of Xmx is 512m.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Yes you are right, during vm arguments jvm overwrites the values, in your case for Xmx it gets 12288m first then again 512, -Xmx value will be overwritten as 512.

Comment: Use only once is the solution

Comment: @Fairoz now i have added the, export  HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS=" -Xmx12288m" property in hive-env.sh. it changed the right most -Xmx value!  have to wait and see...whether am getting the same OOM exception or not!?